# Will setting up a Firestore onSnapshot listener in a useEffect with dependencies result in multiple subscriptions?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks

I'm using `onSnapshot` in a few components and I know I can return the `unsubscribe` function within `useEffect` and it will handle unsubscribing for me when the component unmounts and I don't have to worry about it.

But in my current use cases, useEffect doesn't have any dependencies, it's just:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = db.collection(collectionName).doc(docId).onSnapshot(onNext, onError);
    return unsubscribe;
}, []);
```

Now I have a case where I make a more complicated query to return a sorted and filtered list, and I want to subscribe to changes to the db but also need to update the query when the sort/filter params change.

Typically I'd do that with a useEffect like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = db.collection( ... ).where(...sortOption something...).onSnapshot(...);
    return unsubscribe;    
}, [props.sortOption, props.filterTag]);
```

But in this scenario, would a change to `props.sortOption` or `props.filterTag` result in a new subscription being created without the old unsubscribe being called first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you set up a Firestore onSnapshot listener in a useEffect with dependencies, and the dependencies change, it will result in a new subscription being created and the old one being unsubscribed because your useEffect will rerender again the moment your `[props.sortOption, props.filterTag]` change.

To fix this problem I think you can implement a local cache solution so there will be no unnecessary snapshots being created as Observing your code it looks like you are just sorting and filtering the collection.

You can use cache functionality of firestore to only create snapshot if any change occurred in the firestore db for more info follow this [documentations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline)

Comment: You're saying that it will unsubscribe the existing/previous subscription before creating the new one, though, right?  As long as it's unsubscribing to the old ones then I'm fine

Comment: Nevermind. Found it in the useEffect React docs: "React performs the cleanup when the component unmounts. However, as we learned earlier, effects run for every render and not just once. This is why React also cleans up effects from the previous render before running the effects next time"

Comment: @Reagankm Yeah that is the intended behavior of the `useEffect hook` It will unsubscribe the old Snapshots and will create a new Subscription.